# How to query for an XML value, getting null

Tags: xml, t-sql

I am trying to work with .rdl files to extract certain information.  I have tried this and am getting null as a result and cannot figure it out.  New to xml
Here is the TSql:

```
DECLARE @xml xml   
SET @xml= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet>
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>SyteLine</DataSourceName>
        <CommandType>StoredProcedure</CommandType>
        <CommandText>ItemABCAnalysisSp</CommandText>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
</Report>'  

DECLARE @Value nvarchar(100)
SELECT  @xml.value('(/rd:Report/DataSets/DataSet/Query/CommandType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)' )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a default namespace.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"
        xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
    <DataSets>
        <DataSet>
            <Query>
                <DataSourceName>SyteLine</DataSourceName>
                <CommandType>StoredProcedure</CommandType>
                <CommandText>ItemABCAnalysisSp</CommandText>
            </Query>
        </DataSet>
    </DataSets>
</Report>';

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition')
SELECT  @xml.value('(/Report/DataSets/DataSet/Query/CommandType/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS [CommandType];
```

> Output

```
+-----------------+
|   CommandType   |
+-----------------+
| StoredProcedure |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer  I worked (as i am sure you already knew).  Learned something new about XML  Again, Thanks

Comment: T. Morgan, good to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please mark it as answered. You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image). Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted"